# Itertools islice to output multiple txt lines

Tags: python

I have a collection of txt files. I am trying to loop through this collection of txt files and print off lines 6 & 10 from each file. However, only the first line is being printed in my code. How do I get the second line (for line in islice) to print?

```
import glob2
import csv
from pathlib import Path
from itertools import islice


folder = r"C:\Users\test"

p = Path(folder)
txt_list = list(p.glob('*.txt'))


for i in txt_list:
    print(f"User:{i.stem}; Start date:")
    with open(i) as fin:
        for line in islice(fin, 6, 7):
            print(line[0:10])
        for line in islice(fin, 10, 11):
            print(line[0:10])
```

Comment: The first `islice` consumes 6 elements from `fin` so the second `islice` is looking to consume 10 more items, so this is now the 16th line. You could use `islice(fin, 4, 5)` to get the 10th line. Alternatively, you could do this in one `islice` with a `step`, e.g. `islice(fin, 6, 11, 4)`, which slices from 6, 11 with a step of 4, which would return just lines `6, 10`.

Comment: do you want to print 6th row and 10th row of each file?

Comment: Thanks AChampion. I didn't realise that slices had a relative reference to the previous slices. I used your suggestion islice(fin, 4, 5) in the second instance.